# SoftLayerのWebサイトを英語で表示したい

Tags: softlayer

SoftLayerのWebサイトが日本語されましたが、英語で表示したいこともあります。しかしブラウザの言語設定を英語にしても日本語のサイトにリダイレクトされてしまいます。英語で見る方法はありますか。

Comment: 右上の「言語」からEnglishを選ぶのではダメなのですか？

Answer (score 1):

プロフィール設定で表示言語を変更することができます:

https://control.softlayer.com/account/user/profile